# Transition matrix and coordinate matrix from basis B

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let S be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R^5}$. Let B = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5} be the ordered basis with
$$b_1 = (2, 1, 1, −2, −2)$$
$$b_2 = (0, −2, 4, 5, −4)$$
$$b_3 = (1, −4, 5, 5, −4)$$
$$b_4 = (5, −4, 2, 3, 1)$$
$$b_5 = (4, 1, 2, −3, −2)$$
Form the transition matrix $P = P_{B,S}$ and use it to calculate the coordinate matrix of the vector $v = (1, 1, 2, 0, 3)$ with respect to B.

I think I should start by using each of $b_1$.....$b_5$ as a column to get $[T]_B$. And I am assuming the standard basis would be $\{(1,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0), (0,0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,0,1)\}$. But how do I proceed from there? Please help me understand how such questions should be tackled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transition matrix we are looking for is the inverse of $[T]_B$.

Indeed we have that for $v_S$ represented in the standard basis

$$v_S=[T]_B\cdot v_B \implies v_B=[T]_B^{-1}\cdot v_S$$

where $v_B$ is the representation in the $B$ basis.